# Google Maps API, error with InfoWindow domready event handler

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm setting up a form within an info info window for crowd-sourcing location data.  I've got everything up and running, but I'm trying to copy the lat and lng values into the form elements when the info window pops open.

I've been successful with other event listener on the map div, but when I use the `domready`event handler for the info window I get an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined."

The issue seems to be within the `domready` event listener.

```
// Global Variables
var map, markerWindow, newMarker;

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
    alert(latLng);
    var lat = latLng.lat().toString();
    var lng = latLng.lng().toString();
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerWindow, "domready", function() {
        alert(latLng); // debug alert
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat.slice(0,6);
        document.getElementById('lng').value = lng.slice(0,7);
    });
}
function placeMarker() {
// Setup html form markup for marker pop-up infowindow
    var html = '<div id="htmlform">' +
        '<form action="process.php" method="post" ' +
        'id="mapForm"> <fieldset> <label for="contact">' +
        'Email:</label><input type="text" name="contact"/>' +
        '<br/> <label for="date">Date:</label><input ' +
        'type="text" name="date"/><br/> <label for="desc">' +
        'Description of Sighting:</label><input type="text" ' +
        'name="desc"/><br/> <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="location"/><br/>' +
        '<label for="lng">Longitude:</label><input type="text"' +
        'name="lng" id="lng" class="location"/><br/><input type="submit"' +
        'value="Post Sighting!" onclick="saveData()"/> </fieldset></form>' +
        '</div>';
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker( {
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: "I'm draggable!",
    });
    var markerWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: html,
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {
        newMarker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        markerWindow.open(map, newMarker);
        map.setCenter(e.latLng);
        updateMarkerPosition(newMarker.getPosition());
    });             
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'dragstart', function() {
        markerWindow.close();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'dragend', function(e) {
        newMarker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        markerWindow.open(map, newMarker);
        updateMarkerPosition(newMarker.getPosition());
    });
}
// Run when DOM window loads
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.487, -75.641),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    placeMarker();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did it without the timeout!

```
// Global Variables
var map, markerWindow, newMarker;

function placeMarker() {
// Setup html form markup for marker pop-up infowindow
    var html = '<div id="htmlform">' +
        '<form action="process.php" method="post" ' +
        'id="mapForm"> <fieldset> <label for="contact">' +
        'Email:</label><input type="text" name="contact"/>' +
        '<br/> <label for="date">Date:</label><input ' +
        'type="text" name="date"/><br/> <label for="desc">' +
        'Description of Sighting:</label><input type="text" ' +
        'name="desc"/><br/> <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="location"/><br/>' +
        '<label for="lng">Longitude:</label><input type="text"' +
        'name="lng" id="lng" class="location"/><br/><input type="submit"' +
        'value="Post Sighting!" onclick="saveData()"/> </fieldset></form>' +
        '</div>';
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker( {
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: "I'm draggable!",
    });
    var markerWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: html,
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {
        newMarker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        markerWindow.open(map, newMarker);
        map.setCenter(e.latLng);
    });             
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'dragstart', function() {
        markerWindow.close();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'dragend', function(e) {
        newMarker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        markerWindow.open(map, newMarker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerWindow, 'domready', function() {
      latLng = newMarker.getPosition();
      var lat = latLng.lat().toString();
      var lng = latLng.lng().toString();
      document.getElementById('lat').value = lat.slice(0,6);
      document.getElementById('lng').value = lng.slice(0,7);
    });
}
// Run when DOM window loads
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.487, -75.641),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    placeMarker();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have a different idea without the "domready" listener. I've seen another question where you need to wait a timeout after closing the Infowindow to prevent a click propagation. In your case, waiting some time after the InfoWindow is created allows the latLng to be placed in your mini-form. I wonder if the domready really fires after the form is placed or not.

What I'm suggesting is updating this function:

```
function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
    var lat = latLng.lat().toString();
    var lng = latLng.lng().toString();

    setTimeout(function() { 
      document.getElementById('lat').value = lat.slice(0,6);
      document.getElementById('lng').value = lng.slice(0,7);
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can stop banging my head against the wall now.

Comment: Your original problem is still interesting. In theory it should work, if I find something relevant I'll add another comment. Even if it works, I don't really like the timeout solution.

Comment: I updated the answer with a version where the timeout is inside placeMarker. There might have been something funny with adding a new listener everytime updateMarkerPosition was called. I can't explain why we have trouble with placing the listener in UpdateMarkerPosition.

Comment: Is there a situation where the timer would fail?  I'm pretty new to js, and I can see how it's more of a hack than running a listener on the infowindow domready.  Would the functionality change -- or would the listener yield better results?

Comment: Timeout was a quick hack; I'm also new to Google maps API and async. events, (started about a month ago). I think I can now explain why the original code didn't work: the markerWindow listener was being assigned to an undefined variable, because the listener is created right away when the code runs and sees UpdateMarkerPosition, while markerWindow only gets defined after initialize runs, which has to wait for 'window' to load. The answer is to add the listener after markerWindow is defined. I think the timeout hack fails on a really slow computer where the Infowindow takes too long to appear.